# Laravel 5 - Database connection denied

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

We're making an application for school in which I made a form to add something to the database. I've been following the Laracast, but whenever I try to submit my form to add the contents to the database I get;

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I can use the command `php artisan migrate` perfectly and it creates the tables.
It's just on the application itself that it doesn't work.

Is there any way to solve this?

.env file

```
PP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=Hp7smlDebYOhW04Xn70J0TWfySNI2iAG

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=boost
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=******

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Comment: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=test', 'root', '************');

try this. Sometimes for localhost if you provide host name, it throws error. Better to leave it blanck.

Comment: did you copy-paste the file correctly or do you really have "PP_ENV=local" on your first line? That should definitely be "APP_ENV=local" in order to detect your local environment / also, is your password "root"? I'm not asking for your password, but need to know if you are using the default scotchbox password here. There is no reason to not use root/root in scotchbox

Comment: One other thing you can check is to see if laravel is detecting your local environment or not: put this in a controller somewhere and print the $environment variable. Are you getting "local" as a result? `$environment = App::environment(); echo $environment;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy-paste the file correctly or do you really have `PP_ENV=local` on your first line? That should definitely be `APP_ENV=local` in order to detect your local environment / also, is your password "root"? I'm not asking for your password, but need to know if you are using the default scotchbox password here. There is no reason to not use root/root in scotchbox

One other thing you can check is to see if laravel is detecting your local environment or not: put this in a controller somewhere and print the $environment variable. Are you getting "local" as a result? `$environment = App::environment(); echo $environment;`

Comment: The first issue was that I made a typo in the .env file. Secondly, I was working in the wrong database. I was using my MAMP database instead of the scotchbox database.

Answer (score 1):

Either your username / password combination is wrong, or you have not given the correct grants with the correct hosts to the root user in mysql.

If your username password combination is correct - log into mysql from the command line as root. Then apply the following:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'CHOOSE A PASSWORD';`

Which allows the root user to have all privileges from any host. I would not recommend doing this in a production environment.

Also check your database.php matches your .env file

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sample'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Comment: I'm sure the login details are correct. I'll give the command a shot! Thanks.

Comment: What makes you say you are sure? Have you tested your credentials any other way?

Comment: Yes I have. I can log into my Database using SQLyog using the exact same credentials.

Comment: Ok, then I suspect that your environment might not be set up correctly in Laravel's .env file. Please see my comments above and give us some feedback on that.

Comment: @Jorre Will do asap. Thank you! I suspect I might be using the wrong database.

Comment: @Jorre I did some testing and figured out that I was working on the wrong database. I was using my Mamp database instead of the one that comes with Scotchbox. I changed my .env file accordingly, but now when I try to migrate my tables, I get an error message in my command line.  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). I can connect to the database perfectly using Navicat.

Comment: I was using the wrong environment, like you said @Jorre. Thank you for the help! I'll change the status of this post to answered as the answer is in the comments.

Comment: Please be specific about what answer is the correct answer to your question. I'll post the correct comment as an answer so you can mark that. That way, others can find the answer to similar problems more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install mysql properly.

Make you DB configuration in local.env or the file having .env extension.
You need to provide same configuration which you have provided in database.php file.

Comment: I'm using the .env file for my database config.

Comment: @JorenPolfliet check the folder permission

Comment: Can you paste a full copy of your .env file here? Also, are you using scotchbox / vagrant?

Comment: @jorre updated the OP with the contents of the .env file. I am using scotchbox/vagrant.

Comment: @JorenPolfliet can you comment on the answer and let us know what the exact problem was?